# How to plot n coords to distribute evenly as a ring of points around a circle?

Tags: geometry, circles, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates

Given a circle coord at (100, 100) with radius 25. I want to plot a group of points around the circle to form a ring around it. What is the formula I will need to determine the coordinates of each of these Points?

E.g. I have 10 points to plot in this ring, how to calculate the coordinates to plot them from the circle coords? For each point, I have something like this at the moment: `x: coords.x + (size / 2 * (i + 1))`, which results in this:

[image]

But my desired result should be like this:

[image]

**Context**: To build a table and some chairs in a computer program. The central circle represents the table and the n points represent the chairs.

Comment: Please, provide more information about the context of question.

Comment: Are you familiar with polar coordinates?

Comment: @SteveB Thanks, seems like what I need. But i am not familiar with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parameterize the circle of radius $r$ centered at $z_0$ as $$z(t)=z_0 +re^{it}$$ where $0\leq t<2\pi$. Taking $t_k=2\pi k/n$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$ produces $n$ equally spaced points along the circle.

In terms of real numbers, the center is $(x_0,y_0)$ and the points are given by
$$(x_0+r \cos t_k, y_0+r\sin t_k)
$$

Answer (score 3):

$(x_k, y_k)
=(x_0+r\cos(2k\pi/n), y_0+r\sin(2k\pi/n))
$
for
$k = 0 $ to $n-1$.